# application that execute command in /system

Tags: android, execute

How to create an application that runs a command in  /system.
The command that I need to give is: udpxy -p 4022.
This command will start a program that I have in   /system.

I do not know which commands use in creating application, which execute this command.

If anyone can help I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/udpxy -p 4022");   
    process.waitFor();

} catch (IOException e) {

    throw new RuntimeException(e);

} catch (InterruptedException e) {

    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html

Comment: what code should I use after this line, before arriving at the code you sent?                                                              public class MainActivity extends Activity {